# Quick C++ data to Java transfer

Tags: java, c++, transfer

I'm trying to transfer a stream of strings from my C++ program to my Java program in an efficient manner but I'm not sure how to do this. Can anyone post up links/explain the basic idea about how do implement this?

I was thinking of writing my data into a text file and then reading the text file from my Java program but I'm not sure that this will be fast enough. I need it so that a single string can be transferred in 16ms so that we can get around 60 data strings to the C++ program in a second.

Comment: Why not simply stream data via sockets? For instance by using standard input and standard output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text files can easily be written to and read from upwards with 60 strings worth of content in merely a few milliseconds.

Some alternatives, if you find that you are running into timing troubles anyway:

Use socket programming. http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html.
Sockets should easily be fast enough.

There are other alternatives, such as the tibco messaging service, which will be an order of magnitude faster than what you need: http://www.tibco.com/

Another alternative would be to use a mysql table to pass the data, and potentially just set an environment variable in order to indicate the table should be queried for the most recent entries.

Or I suppose you could just use an environment variable itself to convey all of the info -- 60 strings isn't very much.

The first two options are the more respectable solutions though.

Comment: Do you happen to know what OS facility Tibco uses to do IPC?

Comment: for text files, how would you ensure write protection? so that reads won't happend during writes? is it done automatically by the operating system?

Comment: I believe in some of their products they use shared memory. Beyond that, I don't know.

Comment: Andrew, the operating system won't make the interaction transactional (the database solution avoids this problem). That said, you could add a special string to indicate the write is complete. Another alternative is boost::filesystem which can tell you the last modified time for the file. You could enforce there to be a gap from the current time.

Comment: I guess yet another alternative would be to write it to temporary file in c++. And then use a command like system("cp tmp1.txt input.txt") which would in fact allow the OS to guarantee that the interaction is atomic. I'm confident the copy operation would be well under 1 ms.

Comment: @DoleTheBob You are confident that a write to a file on a HDD with ~15ms latency would be finished in well under 1ms? If the file really has to be written to disk (ie no caching going on) I consider that quite unlikely - how would that work out? I'd use sockets for this kind of stuff - much simpler than shared memory and should be well enough optimized on any modern OS.

Comment: @Voo I just created created a simple file of strings in ubuntu. I then used the "time" command in a loop to copy the file repetitively. The system time that resulted from the timings seemed to be on average 1ms. There probably are caching effects that are occurring, but this nevertheless seems like a reasonable simulation to me of reality.

Comment: @Andrew, one reason to use a Socket is the read can take data as it is sent. There is no additional handshaking you need to do. i.e. Sockets are designed to pass data between process, file are not.

Comment: @DoleTheBob Ok maybe the use case gets by with sequential r/w in which case latency wouldn't be a problem and throughput would be high enough. Sockets are still faster, but in that case it should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization: 
[protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [s11n](http://s11n.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any way you do this will be this fast.  A file is likely to be the slowest and it could be around 10ms total!.  A Socket will be similar if you have to create a new connection as well (its the connect, not the data which will take most time) Using a socket has the advantage of the sender and receiver knowing how much data has been produced. If you use a file instead, you need another way to say, the file is complete now, you should read it. e.g. a socket ;)

If the C++ and Java are in the same process, you can use a ByteBuffer to wrap a C array and import into Java in around 1 micro-second.

Comment: How to to the ByteBuffer thing? Can you provide a link?

Comment: I assume you mean something more specific than what is covered by the Javadoc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html If so what did you have in mind?  BTW Since then I have written a library which is an extension of this strategy https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Bytes